# Custom Error Validation Message Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, error-handling, requiredfieldvalidator

I am doing error validation in Angular as follows.

```
<select ng-model = "color" class = "form-control"
    ng-options = "color as color for color in colors" required>
    <option value="">Choose an option</option> 
</select>

<span ng-show="serviceForm.color.$error.required"> My custom error message </span>
```

The error validation shows up as expected, however, the custom message does not. Instead, I get the following.

[image]

This looks nice but **how do I replace it with my custom message?** It'd be cool if I know where that is coming from so I can edit it.

In addition, my custom message appears if I take out

```
<option value="">Choose an option</option>
```

and then it always appears. Why is this?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/STwm1bXydswP1hTY6TqB?p=preview)

You can replace `HTML5` validation message of that specific field with `space` on form submit. It will prevent displaying the message and will not affect other `HTML5` validation message.

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.ValidateInput = function(){
    var email = document.getElementById("colorId");

    if (email.validity.valueMissing) {
        email.setCustomValidity(" ");
    } else {
        email.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  }
```

**HTML**:

```
<form name='serviceForm'>
      <select name='color' id='colorId' ng-model = "color" class = "form-control"
    ng-options = "color as color for color in colors" required>
         <option value="">Choose an option</option> 
      </select>

     <span ng-show="serviceForm.color.$error.required"> My custom error message </span>
     <input type='submit' ng-click='ValidateInput()' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: the custom error message is always appearing in that plnkr, anyway to fix that? It shouldnt be appearing on default

Comment: Updated my answer and plunkr, please check it.

Answer (score 2):

This message most probably comes from your browser as it does [form validaten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation).

You have to add the `novalidate` attribute to your form to disable it:

```
<form novalidate>
```

Comment: thanks but I do not want to do this specifically because this will disable client side validation?

Comment: I do not want the form to submit until validated

Comment: You added your own validation, so it should not submit before validation anyway.

Comment: for some reason my own validation here doesn't work. The form still submits and no validation messages pop up.

Comment: My own validation only works if I take out "<option value="">Select MBTA color</option>" which should not be taken out

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model = "color" class = "form-control" name="lstColor"
    ng-options = "color as color for color in colors" data-msg-required="Please select color from list" required>
    <option value="">Choose an option</option> 
</select>
```

Try above and hope will solve your problem

Comment: If not then may be problem in validate plugins .. Please is it referencing correctly or not. How ever you can write all the above in extended JS format..

Comment: if($(form).valid()==false){$(form).validate({rules:{lstColor:{required:true}},messages{lstColor:{required:"Please select a color"}});

Comment: Thanks but I am using Angular so I want to avoid regular Javascript as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

`<form novalidate>` can be used to avoid these messages.

But you can also use `setCustomValidity` function when `oninvalid` event occurs to replace it with your custom message.

Like:

```
<input class="form-control" type="email"  required="" placeholder="username" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid email')"></input>
```

Helpful explanation [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/).

Comment: won't form novalidate disable client side validation all together?

Comment: and the problem with this approach is that even after I select an option, the error validation does not recognize it and still ask me to select one